# How to understand "Not lost are you, my dear?"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, word-order

> "**Not lost are you**, my dear?" said a voice in his ear, making him jump.

I guess it simply means "*Are you lost, my dear?*", but I'm not sure. On the other hand, the word order looks odd to me. Is it a common sentence?

A bit context: Harry was lost in Knockturn Alley and he was trying to find a way out to Diagon Alley. Then suddenly, he ran into an aged witch, who said that to Harry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is elliptical.

> [You are] not lost, are you, my dear?

It's colloquial, and I suppose we could consider it a gentler and politer form of the question "Are you lost?"

Comment: I wonder if it could be considered *hyperbaton*?

Comment: Original line is not: "Not lost,  are you, my dear?", but "Not lost are you, my dear?", which makes me think if it's hyperbaton as @aml pointed out?

Comment: And what does putting a label on it do for you in terms of understanding her question?  (Not that I agree with basing an understanding of the question on the way it happened to be punctuated there.)

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I'm not sure if I understand your comment. :(

Comment: What purpose is served by putting the label "hyperbaton" on her question? How does that help you to understand what it means or its tone or register?  It is a perfectly natural way to ask the question.  Compare *Not having second thoughts, are you?*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Maybe, that kind of hyperbaton would add a bit emphasis or something? I don't know, I'm not an expert. So, that's why I asked.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, it might be consider a gentler and politer form of the question compared to "Are you lost?"